# all value from query string after some specific character in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split

My link is as follows:

```
http://localhost:7410/SageFrame/MusicVideoDetails.aspx/id/rLmaJ5gRgXCDxURaTcofOg==
```

I need chracter after /id/ text, which means I need:

`"rLmaJ5gRgXCDxURaTcofOg=="`

How can I do this?

Comment: you can get the last index of the '/' and get last value by using substring function.

Comment: link may have multipal "/" after "/id/" text like http://localhost:7410/SageFrame/MusicVideoDetails.aspx/id/rLma/J5gRgXCDxURa/TcofOg==

Comment: if Word 'id' is fixed then you can sub string from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
string result = link.Substring(link.IndexOf("/id/") + 4);
```